# React native Axios show response on mulitple pages

Tags: react-native, axios

On my API.js i have this code to call API JSON.

```
import { View, Text,Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function APIs() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  const getAPI = () => {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${baseURL}/posts`,
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  };
}
```

How can I show response of that, on few pages?
Lets say on `Home.js` I want to display "id", then on title I want to display "title".
I mean, how can I make call and display it in the parts on multiple pages, each part on different page?

Comment: Just call the API and save its response in the common ancestor of these components

Comment: can i ask for some example how i can do that?

Comment: We would have to see more of the structure of your code, but essentially, in the parent component that renders both your Home and Title, that's where you fetch and save the data, then you would pass each piece to them through props.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a hook:

```
import {View, Text,Button, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function useApiHook({page}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  const getAPI = (location, controller) => {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${baseURL}/${location}`,
      signal: controller.signal,
    })
    .then(res => setData(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  };

  useEffect(() => {
     const controller = new AbortController();
     getApi(page, controller);
     
     return () => controller.abort();
  }, [page])
  
  return data;
}
```

Use in individual pages:

```
const Home = () => {
  const response = useApiHook({page: 'id'});
  console.log(response);
}

const Title = () => {
  const response = useApiHook({page: 'title'});
  console.log(response);
}
```

[react-doc](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#when-to-use-custom-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

If your `<Home />` and `<Title />` components have a common ancestor (`<App />` in the snippet blow), then this component can fetch the data needed, store it, then send each required piece to the corresponding child component through props.

The following snippet showcases a simple example where the `<App />` component fetches the data, then sends the ID of the 1st element to `<Home />` and the title to `<Title />`.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div>1st item ID: {props.firstItemID}</div>
  );
}
function Title(props) {
  return (
    <div>1st item title: {props.firstItemTitle}</div>
  );
}
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => setPosts(response.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Home firstItemID={(posts[0] || {}).id} />
      <Title firstItemTitle={(posts[0] || {}).title} />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```